# Katzer local notification not working - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-notifications, localnotification

I'm talking about this plugin [katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example)

I've used it before few months back. Now I find it changed in many ways. So I tried to create a simple notification.

I installed the plugin

```
cordova plugins add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications
```

Next I tried something simple

```
alert("enter");    

var now             = new Date().getTime(),
_5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5*1000);

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: "Production Jour fixe",
    text: "Duration 1h",
    at: _5_sec_from_now,

});

alert("exit");
```

Nothing happened, no error was showing. Both the alerts were shown perfectly.

Then I tried something more simpler.

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({ message:"Hello World" });

cordova.plugins.notification.local.get(0, function (notification) {
    alert(notification.text); //=> "Hello World"
    alert(notification.message); //=> undefined
});
```

Again nothing. Eclipse ***logcat*** is showing this

```
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422): Uncaught exception from plugin
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.execute(LocalNotification.java:133)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:92)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:812)
03-24 08:25:51.922: E/PluginManager(2422):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-24 08:25:53.890: W/EGL_genymotion(2422): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422): Uncaught exception from plugin
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.execute(LocalNotification.java:133)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6800(WebViewCore.java:57)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:1788)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:689)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:639)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$800(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1153)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:812)
03-24 08:25:55.506: E/PluginManager(2422):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422): Uncaught exception from plugin
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.execute(LocalNotification.java:133)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6800(WebViewCore.java:57)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:1788)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:689)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:639)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$800(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1153)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:812)
03-24 08:25:55.510: E/PluginManager(2422):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I tested in Genymotion emulator 4.2.2 device image & Xperia - android 4.4.4. I've waited for the deviceready event to fire. There is no other error in js. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing? Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem's reason not found but here is the solution.

It was a older project, target sdk was 16, So I updated it to 19.

Re-installed all the plugins. And it's working now. I'm guessing it was some kind dependency / version error. With new plugin versions it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of my project (since it's a legacy project altough it pointed to sdk 19) I had to use version 0.7.8 and the nullPointerException disappeared and everything began working perfectly.

**Procedure**

1. First remove the current plugin which is the latest version.

   ```
   $ phonegap plugin rm de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
   ```
2. Then install version 0.7.8

   ```
   $ phonegap plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification@0.7.8
   ```

Then followed the [docs for that version](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/0.7.8#examples)

**TroubleShooting**

If you have problems with `phonegap plugin rm` you may try re-installin latest version and uninstalling in order to install correctly 0.7.8.

In order to successfully install version 0.7.8, I had to delete some `de.applant.cordova.plugin.localnotification` packages from `/src` and also the *js* folder `de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification` from `/assets/www/plugins`.